# Converting Loop into list comprehension

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list, list-comprehension

Hey so I was recently having trouble of turning this for loop into a list comprehension

```
def str_translate_101(original,old,new):
result = ""
for letter in original:
    if letter == old:
        result += new
    else:
        result += letter
return result
```

can someone help out please?

Comment: Can you add a sample of input and output?

Answer (score 1):

You need a comprehension and a ternary operator:

```
return [letter if letter == old else new for letter in original]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it, but it's a little trickier than a normal list comprehension since you are dealing with a string and not an actual `list`.

```
def str_translate_101(original, old, new):
    result = "".join(new if letter == old else letter for letter in original)
    return result
```

That will return a string, same as your original function.

Comment: Ok, this works, however, he said not to use any dictionaries or anything, like just simplify it, what do it do?

Comment: You aren't using a dictionary here. It's a generator inside Python's `join` function.

Comment: If this helped you now and for future reference, consider marking the answer as accepted.